# Support Offset Column StyleClass in Primefaces Grid CSS?

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

Check the following image.

[image]

To get this layout I have to do with empty div like `<div class="ui-grid-col-2"></div>`.

```
<div class="ui-grid ui-grid-responsive">
    <div class="ui-grid-row">
        <div class="ui-grid-col-1">1</div>
        <div class="ui-grid-col-1">1</div>
        <div class="ui-grid-col-1">1</div>
        <div class="ui-grid-col-1">1</div>
        <div class="ui-grid-col-1">1</div>
        <div class="ui-grid-col-1">1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-grid-row">
        <div class="ui-grid-col-2"></div>
        <div class="ui-grid-col-1">1</div>
        <div class="ui-grid-col-1">1</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there a way like `offset-col-x` as below? Eg : [Bootstrap CSS Offsetting columns](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting)

```
<div class="ui-grid-col-1 offset-col-3">1</div>
```

Comment: So, what is the issue? And why there is java tag?

Comment: @ketan. I would like to do offset column like `bootstrap css`

Comment: Check the PrimeFaces showcase... Something in there? Then check the docs... Something in there? Then you can even check the source (css) if still not sure... Something in there? If not, then it is just not supported. Sorry.. But I think try to create custom css that does this for you.

Comment: @Kukeltje finally to create custom css

Answer (score 1):

The `...-offset-...` classes are for this very purpose:

```
col-xs-offset-x
```